# 401 response when do a POST using scribe oauth java

Tags: java, post, oauth, response, scribe

This does NOT happen when I use it with a GET.

i.e.

this DOES NOT WORK:

```
ProxyAuthenticator pa = new ProxyAuthenticator();
Authenticator.setDefault( pa );

OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder().provider( TwitterApi.class ).apiKey( strAPIKey ).apiSecret( strAPISecret ).build();
Token requestToken = service.getRequestToken();

Scanner in = new Scanner( System.in );
Verifier verifier = new Verifier(in.nextLine());
String url = "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json?status=helllllooooo";

OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest( Verb.POST, url );
service.signRequest( accessToken , request2 );
final Response response = request.send();
```

Response returns a 401. However, using a GET with the above code returns a 200 in response.
i.e.

```
url = "http://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.json";
OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest( Verb.GET, url );
service.signRequest( accessToken, request );

Response resp = request.send();
```

Any ideas what I should do?